# Confusion over term "uniformly distributed" in a probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to determine a joint PDF for random variables $X$ and $Y$ in this problem:

$(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the subset of $\mathbb R^2$, defined by $0<X<2$ and $0 <Y<X^3$.

I'm not sure I understand what's meant by "uniformly distributed". Are they saying all valid $(X,Y)$ combinations have equal probability? How does one even begin to define a joint PDF for this?

Would it be something like

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}k,&0<X<2, 0 <Y<X^3 \\0,& \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$
Where $k$ is some positive constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}k,&0<X<2, 0 <Y<X^3 \\0,& \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$$

where $k$ is a positive constant.

To find $k$, we have to find the area of the support.

we have $$k^{-1}= \int_0^2 x^3 \, dx$$

Comment: What do you mean by "area of the suppose"?

Comment: oops, typo, i meant support

Comment: I've computed $k = 1/4$. How does one interpret this result?

Comment: Your $k$ value is correct. hmm... if you pick two area of the size over the support and call them event $A$ and $B$, we know that the probability of $A$ is equal to the probability of $B$. It just depends on the area.